# The method works fine but get error in my Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a util method(I tested the normal data, it works fine ):

```
util.fillup_obj1_value_with_obj2_value = function(obj1, obj2) {

  for(item in obj2) {
    obj1.hasOwnProperty(item) ? obj1[item] = obj2[item] : ''
  }
}
```

But when I use the method in my Vue.js project,

I will get the bellow error:

> vue.esm.js:578 [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "ReferenceError: item is not defined"

the detail is bellow:

when use the util:

[image]

the next step:

[image]

---

there is my code:

```
export default{
    data(){
      return {
        ...
        form_data: {
          id: '',
          name: '',
          img: '',
          type: ''
        },

methods: {
  edit_btn(h, params) {

    this.$Util.fillup_obj1_value_with_obj2_value(this.form_data, params.row)  # there I use it
  },
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to declare the item first i.e. `let item in obj2`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
util.fillup_obj1_value_with_obj2_value = function(obj1, obj2) {

  for(let item in obj2) {
    obj1.hasOwnProperty(item) ? obj1[item] = obj2[item] : ''
  }
}
```